# Error using Hibernate on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm starting to learn how to use hibernate. I was creating my new application when this error showed up

```
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: ./hibernate.cfg.xml
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: ./hibernate.cfg.xml
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
mar 13, 2015 5:05:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: sample/Event.hbm.xml
Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: sample/Event.hbm.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at samples.ContactosDAO.guardaContacto(ContactosDAO.java:31)
at samples.main.main(main.java:18)
```

I'm really lost in here. Can someone help me out please

Comment: What you are trying to do? When the error occurred? It's too difficult for anyone to give some solution only seeing the log

Comment: well this is pretty much self-explanatory: `org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: sample/Event.hbm.xml not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the error messages. 
On the 4th line from the bottom :`resource: sample/Event.hbm.xml not found`